# Error handling with try and catch in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, try-catch

I want to implement a good error handling in my app, I have forced this file for catching the error.

**App\Services\PayUService**

```
try {
  $this->buildXMLHeader; // Should be $this->buildXMLHeader();
} catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
}
```

**App\Controller\ProductController**

```
function secTransaction(){
  if ($e) {
    return view('products.error', compact('e'));
  }
}
```

And this is what I get.

[image]

I don't know why Laravel is not redirecting me to the view.
Is the error forced right?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You are inside a `namespace` so you should use `\Exception` to specify the global namespace:

```
try {

  $this->buildXMLHeader();

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

In your code you've used `catch (Exception $e)` so `Exception` is being searched in/as:

```
App\Services\PayUService\Exception
```

Since there is no `Exception` class inside `App\Services\PayUService` so it's not being triggered. Alternatively, you can use a `use` statement at the top of your class like `use Exception;` and then you can use `catch (Exception $e)`.

Comment: Thanks! I've already done it. I've seen it as a comment in the official documentation.

Comment: Can you please share more related code and also please tell me about `secTransaction`, what or how this method is innvolved?

Comment: The Alpha, the problem was the namespace. Thanks about worrying.

Comment: When you use `\Exception`, then that class is being searched in where? I mean what is the path of global classes?

Comment: In `Global` namespace, from the root.