# PHP: Undo if Exception occurs

Tags: php, laravel, exception, undo

is there a way in PHP/Laravel to undo serveral steps if an Exception occurs? I know `DB::transaction(function()...`, but it doesn't work in case of using an extern library...

In my case I'm using Stripe:

1.) Create a `Source`

2.) Create a `Customer`

3.) Attach the `Source` to the `Customer`

4.) Create a `Subscription` for the `Customer`

But if there is an **external Exception** from Stripe e.g. in the last step, I would like that the other three steps are not executed and instead an error message is returned.

**Note:** I'm using the Exception Handler from Laravel to `catch` the Exceptions.

I would be happy, if there is a way to solve this problem :-)

---

It's different from the possible duplicate, because I would like to undo several steps if an Exception occurs

Comment: @Martin That won't undo actions that already succeeded in the try clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error handling with try and catch in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444029/error-handling-with-try-and-catch-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Martin I think it doesn't help to undo the previous steps... If an Exception occurs it goes to the `catch` block, but previous steps are executed

Comment: @Johan but if it's a `transaction` as indicated by the OP then this will be cleared rather than part-executed.

Comment: @Martin actually, if they are using DB::transaction, you wouldn't want a try catch block.  You would need an exception to be uncaught for the transaction to rollback.

Comment: @Devon \**slaps forehead*\*.

Comment: You could always, have a rollback history like e.g. "create source and function `$rollback = function () use ($source) { delete source }`" then at each step compose this function with what to do in the event of an error and if you catch an error call the rollback function. or you can ask the Stripe API developers if they have this sort of transnational/atomic access  to their API or ask for a new API call that does those 4 steps atomically. There's no generic solution for this AFAIK

Comment: @SebastianS I think you've confused everyone by mentioning Laravel and `DB::Transaction()`. That's only useful for rolling back changes to your own database, it has nothing to do with remote APIs.

Comment: The docs indicate that if an exception occurs in the transaction block, Laravel will automatically roll the changes back for you.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions.  It doesn't matter if it's an external library causing it or not, if an exception occurs, the changes in your database will be rolled back (even if the external library itself is also making changes to your database, those will be rolled back as well).

Comment: It doesn't make any insert any of the records until you get a confirmation from stripe if you do not want them in your db in that transaction fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use db transactions manually like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

// create your source, customer and attach them

// perform your api call and catch on exection
```

In the catch block of your api call run this:

```
DB::rollBack();
```

If the api call runs successfull run this:

```
DB::commit();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions  (see the manual transactions part at the end specifically)

Comment: Thanks man! You helped me so much! It's just working... Don't know why I did not think it myself. It's easy!